# What is the concept behind Flash Sockets in JavaScript (like socket.io does)?

Tags: flash, websocket, socket.io

I'm interested in Flash sockets and how they can be used in Java Script.
socket.io for example can use Flash sockets, but how is this realized ?
I think there is no swf file.

At the moment I'm more interested in the concept behind than in code.

Answer (score 0):

The [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) library provides everything that's required to use Flash Socket fallback when the `WebSocket` object is not natively available.

The README should provide you with all the information you need.